# Undelegate view events when browser back button pressed

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

Could anyone explain please how to remove events in order to prevent triggering duplication when clicking browser back button. Or is there any way to undelegate events when initalizing view again. Really stuck how to deal with it.
Pressing back button and then back again causes firing events for multiple times. When saving model form data for instance. Thank you.

```
var App = {};

// extending models, collections etc.

App.SamplesCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '#samples',
    template: _.template($('#sample-edit-template').html()),
    events: {
        'click a.sample-item': 'onEdit'
    },
    render: function(){
        this.$el.append(this.template());
        var $sample_list = this.$el.find('ul#sample-list');
        this.collection.each(function(sample) {
            var rendered = new App.CategoryView({model: sample}).render().el;
            $sample_list.append(rendered);
        });
    },

    onEdit: function(e) {
        this.undelegateEvents();
        // go to edit view
        Backbone.history.navigate(e.target.getAttribute('href'), {trigger: true});
        return false;
    }

});

App.SampleEditView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '#samples',
    template: _.template($('#sample-edit-template').html()),
    events: {
        'click button.save': 'onSave',
        'click button.cancel': 'onCancel',
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.append(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },

    onSave: function() {
        this.undelegateEvents();
        var data = Helpers.getFormData(this.$el.find('form'));
        this.model.save(data);
        // go back to index view
        Backbone.history.navigate('/samples', {trigger: true});
        return false;
    }

});

App.SamplesRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        'samples': 'index',
        'samples/edit/:id': 'edit'
    },

    index: function() {
        App.samples = new App.SamplesCollection;
        App.samplessView = new App.SamplesCollectionView({collection: App.samples});
    },

    edit: function(id) {
        App.sampleEdit = new App.SampleEdit({id: id});
        App.sampleEditView = new App.SampleEditView({model: App.sampleEdit})
    }

});

App.samplesRouter = new App.SamplesRouter;

Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, hashChange: false});
```

Comment: You probably have zombie views. You should share the minimal code that reproduces this. BTW you don't need to undeligate events when initializing view again (that is the wrong approach and I doubt if it's possible), what you need to do is make sure to remove all listeners before removing the view.

Comment: I've added sample code. I know that something I am doing wrong. Could you please clarify that. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: There is no code that appends your views to the DOM...? Then how does this even work..? If you don't remove the existing view, how is it's template removed when moving to a different route?

Comment: This is just a sample with skipped blocks not the working example. All the functionality that implements moving between the views in here. Code has a basic render function.

Comment: So I should implement removing the view, right? Before navigating to different route? How can I detect pressing back browsers button?

Comment: Forget back button. It should be something like `if(App.samples) App.samples.remove(); App.samples = new App.SamplesCollection;` then there is a question... If you already have a view instance, how come it's not visible in UI? That's why I asked about rendering. There is probably something wrong with the way these views are connected to DOM.

Comment: I've added render implementation to the code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have many views pointing to same element `#samples`. You can't remove one view because if you call `view.remove()` your other view's element is gone.
And as long as that that element exists in DOM, the view you thought to be gone will exist in memory since the shared element has event handlers referring the view instance.

If you want to delegate display functionality and edit functionality under same element, do it in same view using something like show/hide techniques without creating a new view instance.

Otherwise they should have it's own elements, you shouldn't have two view instances pointing to same element. While switching to a different view, make sure you call it's `remove()` method which removes the element from DOM and invokes `undelegateEvents` so that it get's garbage collected properly.